# Mutiny Quarkus : Can you use Mutiny reactive programming in ArrayLists?

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-reactive

I'm trying to learn Reactive programming in quarkus and run into a problem. I want to make a simple employee system without any database, just the ArrayList with the Employees but in every article  and video tutorial i watched and read , there were all using Databases.Is there a way to use Mutli and Uni in just an ArrayList and Is it worth it at all?
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do something like:

```
public class Fruit {

    public final String name;
    public final String description;

    public Fruit(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
}

@Path("/fruits")
public class FruitResource {

    private final Set<Fruit> fruits = Set.of(new Fruit("Apple", "Winter fruit"), new Fruit("Pineapple", "Tropical fruit"));

    @GET
    public Uni<Set<Fruit>> list() {
        return Uni.createFrom().item(fruits);
    }
}
```

where all you are doing is returning a `Set` of `Fruit` objects via a `Uni` - no database or anything